# Email address order

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Could someone tell me how I sort the email addresses I have put in the BCC field in alphabetical order?  I have sent an e-mail to a large number of people that I have exported from a database.  I need to put these in alphabetical order so that I can find individual people and check there is no duplication.  I can't see this option anywhere.  Many thanks.

Comment: WHat program, what operating system? Needs more info.

Comment: Possibly sort the email addresses alphabetically when exporting from the database.  Not sure how the database and Outlook are connected.  Any clarification you can provide would be helpful.

Comment: Do you even need to do this? If you send an email `bcc: fred, barney, fred`, does fred get two copies? I expect that Outlook will de-dupe the list.     ...     Unless you're talking about de-duping `fred@work.com, fflintstone@home.com`.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't do it by hand, especially because you'd need tool for sorting anyway. So why not go a step further and use a simple script in some dynamic language to do the job?

Hmm, thinking about that, easiest for you to use would be JavaScript, since its built-in in pretty much every browser and does not require any additional installations, so I just [wrote a quick script to clean-up duplicate entries in comma-separated string and uploaded it to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HcK8q/2/) <---- click this shiny link, copy/paste entire Bcc: line into "Comma-separated address list" prompt and then copy/paste results from "Copy/paste unique results".

Of course this will clean-up any comma-separated list from duplicates, not just email addresses. Here's also a copy of this script packed in one line, for preservation and for use as bookmarklet content if you prefix it with `javascript:`.

```
var cs = prompt("Comma-separated list:"); var separated = cs.split(/\s*,\s*/); var uniq = {}; var uniq_list = []; for (var idx = 0; idx < separated.length; idx++) { if (!uniq[separated[idx]]){ uniq[separated[idx]] = 1; uniq_list.push(separated[idx]) }; }; prompt("Copy/paste unique results:", uniq_list.join(', '))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a great tutorial on how to sort with Excel

First, copy the entire data, and paste into a new workbook in excel.

Select the cell, and select: Data to Cells option, and select ',' as the seperator.

The tutorial is: http://www.contextures.com/xlSort01.html

HTH